# Three.js @googlemaps/three overlay onDraw function does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, three.js

I'm creating React app using Google Map API and Three.js.
Basically I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxAwkT9M6rM
https://github.com/leighhalliday/google-maps-threejs

onDraw seems to be added to the overlay, however the content of the function is empty, whereas onBefore I can run it normally (I can see '("onBeforeDraw");' in my console)

Why onDraw gets empty? How do I make it work?

This is the documentation:
https://googlemaps.github.io/js-three/classes/ThreeJSOverlayView.html#onDraw

This is my current code (I replaced "@ubilabs/threejs-overlay-view" with "@googlemaps/three" Overlay is now imported from @googlemaps/three)

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Wrapper } from "@googlemaps/react-wrapper";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { ThreeJSOverlayView } from "@googlemaps/three";
import { LineGeometry } from "three/examples/jsm/lines/LineGeometry.js";
import { Line2 } from "three/examples/jsm/lines/Line2.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import { getGeocode, getLatLng } from "use-places-autocomplete";
import "./App.css";

const mapOptions = {
  center: {
    lat: 43.66293,
    lng: -79.39314,
  },
  zoom: 17,
  heading: 320,
  tilt: 90,
  mapId: "MAP_ID",
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper apiKey={import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}>
      <MyMap />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

function MyMap() {
  const [route, setRoute] = useState();
  const [map, setMap] = useState();
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const instance = new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, mapOptions);
    setMap(instance);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref} id="map" />
      {map && <Direction setRoute={setRoute} />}
      {map && route && <Animation map={map} route={route} />}
    </>
  );
}

const ANIMATION_MS = 10000;
const FRONT_VECTOR = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);

function Animation(props) {
  const overlayRef = useRef();
  const trackRef = useRef();
  const carRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    props.map.setCenter(props.route[Math.floor(props.route.length / 2)], 17);

    if (!overlayRef.current) {
      overlayRef.current = new ThreeJSOverlayView({
        anchor: {
          lat: mapOptions.center.lat,
          lng: mapOptions.center.lng,
          altitude: 0,
        },
        upAxis: "Y",
      });
      overlayRef.current.setMap(props.map);
    }

    // Creaet a curve
    const points = props.route.map((p) =>
      overlayRef.current.latLngAltitudeToVector3(p)
    );
    const curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points);

    if (trackRef.current) {
      overlayRef.current.scene.remove(trackRef.current);
    }

    trackRef.current = createTrackFromCurve(curve);
    overlayRef.current.scene.add(trackRef.current);

    console.log("overlay", overlayRef.current);

    const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.SphereGeometry(105, 32, 16),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
      })
    );
    sphere.position.copy(
      overlayRef.current.latLngAltitudeToVector3({
        lat: 43.66293,
        lng: -79.39314,
      })
    );
    overlayRef.current.scene.add(sphere);

    // Model (car)
    loadModal().then((model) => {
      if (carRef.current) {
        overlayRef.current.scene.remove(carRef.current);
      }
      carRef.current = model;
      overlayRef.current.scene.add(carRef.current);
      console.log("carRef.current inside", carRef.current);
    });

    console.log("overlayRef.current", overlayRef.current);

    overlayRef.current.onBeforeDraw = () => {
      console.log("onBeforeDraw");
    };

    overlayRef.current.onDraw = () => {
      console.log("onDraw", carRef.current);
      trackRef.current.material.resolution.copy(
        overlayRef.current.getViewportSize()
      );

      if (carRef.current) {
        const progress = (performance.now() % ANIMATION_MS) / ANIMATION_MS;
        console.log("progress", progress);
      }

      overlayRef.current.requestRedraw();
    };

    return () => {
      overlayRef.current.scene.remove(trackRef.current);
    };
  }, [props.route]);

  return null;
}

async function loadModal() {
  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  const object = await loader.loadAsync("/low_poly_car/scene.gltf");
  const scene = object.scene;
  scene.scale.setScalar(0.5);

  return scene;
}

function createTrackFromCurve(curve) {
  const points = curve.getSpacedPoints(curve.points.length * 10);
  const positions = points.map((point) => point.toArray()).flat();

  const lineGeometry = new LineGeometry().setPositions(positions);
  const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    linewidth: 38,
  });

  return new Line2(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
}

function Direction(props) {
  const [origin, setOrigin] = useState("75 Yonge Street Toronto");
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState("27 Front St E Toronto");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDirections(origin, destination, props.setRoute);
  }, [origin, destination]);

  return (
    <div className="directions">
      <h2>Direction</h2>
      <h3>Origin</h3>
      <p>{origin}</p>
      <h3>Destination</h3>
      <p>{destination}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

async function fetchDirections(origin, destination, setRoute) {
  const [originResults, destinationResults] = await Promise.all([
    getGeocode({ address: origin }),
    getGeocode({ address: destination }),
  ]);

  const [originLocation, destinationLocation] = await Promise.all([
    getLatLng(originResults[0]),
    getLatLng(destinationResults[0]),
  ]);

  // Direction Service
  const service = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
  service.route(
    {
      origin: originLocation,
      destination: destinationLocation,
      travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    },
    (result, status) => {
      if (status === "OK" && result) {
        const route = result.routes[0].overview_path.map((path) => ({
          lat: path.lat(),
          lng: path.lng(),
        }));
        setRoute(route);
      }
    }
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// onDraw
onDraw: () => {…}
length: 0
name: ""
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
[[FunctionLocation]]: App.jsx:117
[[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
```